# When using dplyr, how to summarise data with group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble *df* of the form

```
Province/State      Country/Region       Lat   Long `1/22/20` `1/23/20` `1/24/20` `1/25/20` 
 1 NA                 Afghanistan         33    65        0         0         0         0    
 2 NA                 Albania             41.2  20.2      0         0         0         0         
 3 NA                 Algeria             28.0  1.66      0         0         0         0        
 4 NA                 Andorra             42.5  1.52      0         0         0         0      
 5 NA                 Angola             -11.2  17.9      0         0         0         0
 6 NA                 Antigua and Bar…    17.1 -61.8      0         0         0         0 
 7 NA                 Argentina          -38.4 -63.6      0         0         0         0         
 8 NA                 Armenia             40.1  45.0      0         0         0         0             
 9 Australian Capi…   Australia          -35.5  149.      5         0         0         0              
 10 New South Wales   Australia          -33.9  151.      6         0         0         0
```

and I would like to get the total number for each date column for every country like:

```
Country/Region        `1/22/20` `1/23/20` `1/24/20` `1/25/20` 
 Afghanistan              0         0         0         0    
 Albania                  0         0         0         0         
 Algeria                  0         0         0         0        
 Andorra                  0         0         0         0      
 Angola                   0         0         0         0
 Antigua and Bar…         0         0         0         0 
 Argentina                0         0         0         0         
 Armenia                  0         0         0         0             
 Australia               11         0         0         0
```

It seems that I would just have to write:

```
df %>% 
  select(-"Province/State", -"Lat" , -"Long") %>% 
  group_by("Country/Region") %>%
  summarise(sum)
```

but R keeps throwing the error: *Error: Column `sum` is of unsupported type function*;
in fact, it does not work for any function.

If instead I use summarise_all, I get: *Error in .Primitive("sum")(`Country/Region`) : 
invalid 'type' (character) of argument*, which is understandable since "Country/Region" is 
column of characters.

What am I doing wrong? How can I perform this simple computation?

Comment: I think you want `summarise_all(sum)` to sum all the columns, otherwise `summarise` alone would expect you to specify a column.

Comment: And you've got `$>$` after the `select` statement. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately summarise_all gives an error that is written in the question. The solution in the question marked as duplicate does not work for me.

Comment: Don't use double quotes in the group_by. `""`. Use backticks ``.

Comment: Thank you! Where could I have learned that? Could you please give some explanation?

Comment: You don't normally need to enclose variable names with quotes in the tidyverse. But if they contain metacharacters, such as `/`, then you need backticks.

Comment: Thank you very much!